# Selective alpha or removing alpha

Tags: texturing, node-editor, transparency

This is my setup, I have a plane that I wanted to display 2 textures. The first texture I want to show only part of it. In this example, it is the circular ring. For the second texture, I also wanted to show only a portion of it, this is represented by the blue circle on my example.

What I wanted to do is to crop out the textures, i.e. the ring and the circle, but not actually make the object transparent. In my example, I should still see the rest of the object which is a plane. Anyone knows a better way to do this?

[image: reference image and node setup]

Here's the blend file I used as reference:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see something on your plane instead of transparency, plug the 2 nodes you use as alpha layers into a *Converter > Math > Add*, plug this *Math* into the factor of a *Mix Shader*, in this *Mix Shader* plug your current setup plus the background you want to see (here a yellow *Diffuse*):

[image]

Comment: thanks, kind sir, you are my saviour! that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. sorry, I had to type this on the comment, but I felt it isn't enough to accept the answer, I had to express my gratitude. :)

Comment: thanks, there may be a simpler way but I didn't want to change your current setup

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a side-note, it may not apply to your case. But in general, if you see shaders with identical settings but different colors being mixed, you should consider mixing the colors before they get to the shader, rather than mixing shaders; it's cheaper.

And, if you don't need Alpha further down your line, you can avoid that, too, by using the existing black-and-white masks as mix factors:

[image]

....

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I need every bit of information and help I could get. And your explanation is very nice and clear too. :) I will keep this on my notes.